# What is the purpose of index.js in the FabCar chaincode?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, blockchain

I could not figure out the purpose of index.js in FabCar chaincode and where is the module.exports line in the file exactly being used?

Comment: Which version of HLFabric are you using?

Comment: Can you provide the path which fabcar chaincode you are refering?

Comment: @ShubhamChadokar the path is /fabric-samples/chaincode/fabcar/javascript .

Answer (score 0):

This fabcar chaincode is written using [fabric-contract-api](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fabric-contract-api) npm module.

You can notice that fabcar contract is Extends Contract

```
const { Contract } = require('fabric-contract-api');

class FabCar extends Contract
```

fabric-contract-api is a high level API for application developers. You can read the [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fabric-contract-api).

Check the package.json

```
"main": "index.js",
"scripts": {
        "start": "fabric-chaincode-node start"
      }
```

On start the npm module which is used checks the index.js and use the mentioned contract.

This npm package fabric-contract-api is in experimental phase.
Hope it helped. Please add any link if you find helpful for related to this.